# How to find more than one variable in a string using preg_match?

Tags: php, regex

How to find more than one variable in a string using preg_match?

I have below string in a php variable, where the variable values to be found are highlighted.

```
$var = '<div class="CK mag10">OKT: **VARVALUE1**<span class="OK1 OK2">|</span>MOK: **VARVALUE2**<span class="OK1 OK2">|</span>ISIN: **VARVALUE3**<span class="OK1 OK2">|</span>SOCCER: **VARVALUE4**</div>';
```

I have written this code:

```
$found_matches = preg_match('/\<div class=\"CK mag10\">OKT: ([0-9A-Za-z]+)\<span class=\"OK1 OK2\"\>|\<\/span\>MOK: ([0-9A-Za-z]+)\<span class=\"OK1 OK2\"\>|\<\/span>ISIN: ([0-9A-Za-z]+)\<span class=\"OK1 OK2\"\>|\<\/span>SOCCER: ([0-9A-Za-z]+)\<\/div\>/i', $var, $matches);
```

but it is giving me only one value not all variables value.
Is there any way to get all variable values stacked in that single array **$matches** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this function is useful for you:

```
preg_match_all("/(?<=startTag)[\w]+(?=endTag)/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

**startTag** = change its string to the default string before of the word you want to extract.

**endTag** = change its string to the default string after ends the word you want to extract.

[Sample](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/coO) - `preg_match` or `preg_match_all`

**Exit**

```
array(
    0   =>  array(
        0   =>  VARVALUE1
        1   =>  VARVALUE2
        2   =>  VARVALUE3
        3   =>  VARVALUE4
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to

1. Parse HTML with DOM
2. Obtain results in a safe way

Here is a sample code:

```
<?php
$html = <<<HTML
<div class="CK mag10">OKT: VARVALUE1<span class="OK1 OK2">|</span>MOK: VARVALUE2<span class="OK1 OK2">|</span>ISIN: VARVALUE3<span class="OK1 OK2">|</span>SOCCER: VARVALUE4</div>
HTML;
$arr = array();
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links = $xp->query('//div[@class="CK mag10"]');
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $chks = explode('|', $link->nodeValue);
    foreach ($chks as $chk) {
        if (preg_match('/\s*[A-Z]+:\s+(.*)/', $chk, $matches)) {
           array_push($arr, $matches[1]);
        }
    }
}
print_r($arr);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/8sezbI)